# How to set text on textarea in another class JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I've a problem with set text on textarea from another class. After done simple script i want to change textarea in another class with InputStreamReader. Error which i have is :java.lang.NullPointerException.
I've tried to make get() and set() methods and if i made string with initialized value in class which contains InputStreamReader and try to sysout in class with textarea it shows me that string but if i want to setText there is an NPE.
Is SimpleStringProperty good solution ?

This is output:

```
            Process process;
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(PATH_TO_SIKULI + " -r " + s.toString());
            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
            String as=null;
            stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(as);

            while ((as = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder=stringBuilder.append(as+"\n");
            }
            while ((as = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder=stringBuilder.append(as+"\n");
            }
            try {
                process.waitFor();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
    }
```

Class with TextArea

public class ResultController implements Initializable{

```
@FXML
public TextArea resultTextArea;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

        }
    });



}
```

Answer (score 1):

that throws your NullPointer:

```
String as=null; 
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(as);
```

as the documentation pretty good descripes you cannot pass `null` to the 
`StringBuilder` constructor.
But this is here the case: `as = null`

> java.lang.StringBuilder.StringBuilder(String str)
>
> Constructs a string builder initialized to the contents of the
>   specified string. The initial capacity of the string builder is 16
>   plus the length of the string argument.
>
> Parameters: str the initial contents of the buffer. Throws:
>   NullPointerException - if str is null

Comment: ok, but next initializing is on 2 while's loop
stringBuilder=stringBuilder.append(as+"\n");